# ADD a existing API without server downtime

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can you ADD an existing API without server downtime on wso2 ESB?we want to deploy it onto server without interfering with coming live request?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can replace the existing API configuration in the deployment folder or the CAPP (If you used capps to deploy the api) and you do not need a server restart to apply changes.